# Meaning of small numbers given in round brackets

Tags: keyboard

what is the meaning of the numbers given in small curly brackets above/below a given number. Example (3) above 2 on note F# A major Pentatonic scale[image]

Answer (score 7):

All the numbers are suggested fingerings. The numbers in brackets are alternative fingering ideas. To me, it's a personal thing, and part of the job of learning a piece is to work out my own fingering - my fingers are not those of the person who's trying to be helpful !

Comment: yes, this are alternative fingerings

Comment: Though I agree that every musician should develop their own fingerings, there are commonalities between most people's hands. A beginner might choose a more "obvious" fingering without taking other factors such as speed, comfort, and ergonomics into account, so suggested fingerings are, as they are trying to be, pretty helpful.

Answer (score 2):

As Tim said, these are the finger numbers. I assume this is a handbook to learn piano, so playing with these fingers is supposed to help you learn proper technique. The numbers go from 1 (thumb) up to 5 (pinky).

Comment: +1 as it was not always use to play keyboard with the thumb and not all cultures are counting the fingers the same way.